# Interlocked.Increment внутри lock

Tags: c#, многопоточность, lock, блокировки

Смотрю на код из [статьи](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/09/06/managed-object-internals-part-2-object-header-layout-and-the-cost-of-locking/) и не могу понять, в чём смысл использования `Interlocked.Increment` внутри `lock`. Зачем он там?

```
public class Node
{
    public const int InvalidId = -1;
    private static int s_idCounter;

    private int m_id;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_id == InvalidId)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    if (m_id == InvalidId)
                    {
                        m_id = Interlocked.Increment(ref s_idCounter);
                    }
                }
            }

            return m_id;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представьте, что у вас несколько экземпляров `Id` в многопоточном приложении и если они используются в разных потоках (каждый - в своем), оба потока могут оказаться одновременно внутри `lock`, т.к. для блокировки будут использованы разные объекты (`this` же). Поэтому использование `Interlocked` здесь не лишнее и оправдано.

Использование `Interlocked` было бы не нужно, если бы для всех/разных экземпляров для блокировки был использован один какой-то специально созданный статический объект, но это привело бы к некоторой потере скорости при одновременном доступе к разным экземплярам `Id`.

Comment: _"но это привело бы к некоторой потере скорости при одновременном доступе к разным экземплярам Id"_ - почему привело бы? Здесь же всё равно lock, только другой. Логично либо два Interlocked'а, либо нормальный lock, а тут какой-то гибрид.

Comment: Потому что все потоки, не зависимо от того с разными экземплярами `Id` или с одним и тем же они работают, ждали бы, пока один из них выйдет из `lock`. А здесь нужно будет подождать только лишь при использовании того же самого экземпляра. А почему гибрид - надо спрашивать у автора, но, вроде, выглядит нормально и хорошо читается, да и объектов не нужно дополнительных заводить

Comment: Получается, `Interlocked.Increment` намного эффективнее, чем пять операций внутри lock'а (сравнить, инкрементировать (прочитать, увеличить, записать), присвоить)?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну лучше ведь заблокировать всех на 3 операции, и лишь некоторых на 5, чем абсолютно всех на 5? :) Хотя, конечно, какой вариант покажет себя лучше зависит от контекста, если много потоков работают с одним и тем же экземпляром - то будет быстрее работать код с одной блокировкой, но если в основном идет работа с разными экземплярами, то этот код будет быстрее, я так думаю...

Comment: Я про то, что у `Interlocked.Increment` тоже ведь есть накладные расходы - неужели они меньше этих 2 операций? Или вероятность, что второй if выдаст false настолько велика, что всё это перевешивает?

Comment: Вообще Албахари говорит, что `Interlocked` - это _неблокирующая конструкция синхронизации_ и работает очень быстро: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Interlocked

Comment: `Interlocked.Increment` блокирует шину передачи данных до получения сигнала, что позволяет выполнять атомарные операции. Фактически, это аппаратная блокировка, которая, разумеется, работает на порядок быстрее, чем `lock`

Comment: @Qwertiy два Interlocked'а сделали бы возможным пропуск id, иногда важно этого избежать. Впрочем, автор той статьи выбрал lock по более простой причине - он же измерял производительность лока...